# How can I "unroll" this sigma notation as a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

In my java programming class, we have a lab assignment (not worth points) to implement several recursive methods. I have completed the recursive method based on a given recursive function, and I have completed a necessary factorial recursive method for the remaining portion, which is a sigma series that I am currently having a hard time wrapping my head around.

We are given this formula:

[s(n) = sigma[(s(n - i) - 1) / i!, i = 1, n] and s(0) = 0](https://technology.heartland.edu/faculty/todds/csci131/labs/recursive_sequence/img26.gif)

and I have written out the results for s(1)-s(5) (using my graphing calculator to verify my answers as I go), but I am having difficulty figuring out how to correctly implement this recursive process.

I have built a "sigma" method that works appropriately to the best of my knowledge, and so I think I have issues with my "formula" method. Worst of all, the formula looks right (to the best of my thinking) and the code is currently getting stuck in an infinite loop.

```
// ... Rest of code omitted for brevity
private static double sequence2(int i) {
    if (i <= 0) { return 0; }
    return (sequence2(max - i) - 1) / factorial(i); // max is defined in other code
}
private static double sigma(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) { return 0; }
    return sequence2(n) + sigma(n - 1);
}
private static int factorial(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) { return 1; }
    return n * factorial(n - 1);
}
```

Where should I begin for figuring out how to correctly unroll this recursive sequence?

Comment: What is `max` and why would you change a multiplication of factorial into division?

Comment: It's supposed to be division, that's an error in my original post of the formula. `max` is a user defined int (min = 1) that is validated before calling the recursive method.

Comment: and what is `i`, what do you believe `max-i` gives you?

Comment: `max - i` is a given part of the original sequence definition. If you click the link in my post, it shows the correct notation, which may be more clear than my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to my teacher, he provided the following method as an acceptable way to calculate the correct values:

```
static double generateSigmaSequnce(int n) {
    if (n < 1) { return 0; }
    double sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        sum += (generateSigmaSequnce(n - i) - 1) / factorial(i);
    }
    return sum;
```

This code does indeed return the correct values for the sigma sequence, but to my mind it is somewhat unsatisfactory as we've had to use an iterative loop to drive behavior in an exercise in recursion. I will be puzzling out from here to determine if I can create a new method/augment this method to include a recursive summation, but for the time being (and in my teacher's own code) this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

According to the formula you've linked the recursion should be(changing the name of the variables to correlate) :

```
private static double sequence2(int n) {
    if (n == 0) { return 0; }
    return (sequence2(n-1) - 1) / factorial(n-1); 
}
```

this shall generate the sequence in the reverse order from `S(n-1), S(n-2) ... S(1)`

Comment: This is not correct, as it does not sum the series. For example, `n=2` should equal `-5/2` but in your example it returns `-2`.

Comment: `s(2)` should unroll as `(s(2-1)-1)/1! + (s(2-2)-1)/2!` where `s(1)` unroll as `(s(1-1)-1)/1!`, which returns a value of `-1` from `(0-1)/1` and so `s(2)` calculates `(-1-1)/1 + (0-1)/2` and returns `-5/2`

Comment: @studioKeywi That is what the above code does as well. Maybe you're ignoring the sigma part in the answer, which I believe can remain as it is.

Comment: With your `sequence2` and my `sigma` methods, we see how it unrolls:

`sigma(2)` becomes `s2(2)+sigma(1)`, `s2(2)` becomes `(s2(1)-1)/factorial(1)`, `s2(1)` becomes `(s2(0)-1)/factorial(0)`, `s2(0)` and `factorial(0)` return `0` and `1` respectively, and so `s2(1)` returns `-1` and `factorial(1)` returns `1`, so `s2(2)` returns `-2` (which is already wrong), but then `sigma(1)` calculates `s2(1)+sigma(0)`; `s2(1)` we've already shown is `-1` and `sigma(0)` returns `0`, so `sigma(1)` returns `-1` and finally `sigma(2)` returns `-3`. `sigma` adds correctly; the `sequence` itself is wrong.